# Loopback 4: Explorer error: Could not render n, see the console

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have this error in loopback4 explorer (see the image)

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGCq4.png)

The API call works (I have try it in postman), but I can use it in the loopback explorer interface. Any idea?

In the console the error is that:
[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTTM1.png)

```
@post('/gameshits/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Return the number of correct answers',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {count: Number},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async gamesHits(
    @param.path.string('id') id: string,
    @requestBody() answers: Array<number>,
  ): Promise<object> {

    let game: Game = await this.gameRepository.findById(id);
    var hits = 0;
    var i = 0;
    if (typeof game.gameBody != undefined){
      game.gameBody!.forEach( (element) => {
        console.log (element)
        console.log (element.correctAnswer);
        console.log (answers[i]);
        if (element.correctAnswer == answers[i]){
          hits++;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
    return {count: hits};

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow the advice and check what is there in console? :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko a really stupid question. I am new in that...but where is the console? where can I see that?

Comment: Assuming you are using Chrome you could press <kbd>F12</kbd> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I do that. Now I feel really stupid :). I have update with the error of the console. Any idea? What I have to change in the code to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem.